# Given a Facebook page URL, save as ID in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, twitter

tl;dr: In Rails, what is the recommended way of taking one form of input (in this case, a URL), and converting it to something else (in this case, a Facebook ID using their graph API) before saving it?

I'm working on creating a (very simple) site to track some Facebook and Twitter accounts. In both cases, I want a user to enter a URL into a form, but I'd like to then convert that URL into a (Facebook or Twitter) ID before saving to the database, for the sake of consistency and future-proofing.

My experience with Rails is very limited (just finished Michael Hartl's RailsTutorial), and I'm not sure how to set up my form to perform some action on the input before saving it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common pattern for this, is doing it in the before_save callback (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). However, as these operation(s) sometime take very noticeable time, it's better to do it in the background using DelayedJob, Resque, Sidekiq or at least girl_friday. The enqueuing of the job can still go into the before_save callback. And you probably want to check there if the id is already known, so it doesn't need to fetch it again.